# How can I extract date and time from a Long type variable in Kotlin on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using an API from USGS website.

```
"properties": {
    "mag": 3.2,
    "place": "Puerto Rico region",
    "time": 1164925597950,
    "updated": 1415323859614,
    "tz": null
}
```

The time is in milliseconds. I want to extract  date & time from these milliseconds. How can I do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

fun convertLongToTime (time: Long): String {
    val date = Date(time)
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    return format.format(date)
}
```

This would work in Kotlin, you can change the format in SimpleDataFormat according to how you want.

Answer (score 1):

From API level 26 on (Android) or if the JVM is your target, you can use the Java 8 Date API:

```
val date = Instant
        .ofEpochMilli(1164925597950)
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) // change time zone if necessary
        .toLocalDateTime()

val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
println(formatter.format(date)) // 2006-11-30 23:26
```

Below API level 26:

```
val date = Date(1164925597950)

val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
println(formatter.format(date)) // 2006-11-30 23:26
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the way i use in Java. You just simply change it for kotlin.**

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(dateInMillis)));

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your milliseconds to Date Constructor `Date(timeinMillis)` it will return the date.